# Pandas- how to compute a rolling forward 10/backward 10 mean absolute deviation?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I've been reading documentation on the rolling() funciton and I can't seem to find a way to incorporate both a forward and backward window at the same time. What I want to do is compute the mean absolute deviation (or even standard deviation) of the forward 10 and past 10 events for outlier analysis.

I was able to compute mean for forward/past 10 in a hacky way by doing

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'date': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2017', end='12/31/2017'),
        'value': np.random.rand(365)})

first_10 = df.rolling(window=10, win_type='triang')['value'].mean().shift().reset_index()

last_10 = df[::-1].rolling(window=10, win_type='triang')['value'].mean().shift().reset_index()
```

and then

```
pd.merge(first_10, last_10, on = ['level_1']).set_index(['level_1']).mean(axis=1)
```

But because you can't just average two MADs together to get the MAD for that window, I can't do this. Does anyone have a more robust way to use the rolling function for calculations like this? Feels like there has to be away using some sort of shift function.

Appreciate the help on this.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this

```
mad = lambda x: np.fabs(x - x.mean()).mean()

s.rolling(window=60).apply(mad, raw=True).plot(style='k')
```

From Pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#method-summary)